# how can I skip 1st header row in db2 load

Tags: database, db2, loader

I am loading data from csv file to db2 database table by writing a db2Loader.
I have successfully loaded the csv file into db2 database table with its header row as well.

I want a way to skip that 1st row i.e. the headers row.
i have tried using WARNINGCOUNT 1, IGNORE 1, NOHEADER but nothing is working as i want.
might be i am placing it in wrong position.

How can I make it work?

here is the query I am trying to run.

```
"LOAD CLIENT FROM 'dataFile' OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL 'modifier' 
NOCHARDEL MESSAGES 'dataFile' INSERT INTO 'tableName' (columns) 
STATISTICS NO NONRECOVERABLE "
```

I am using load instead of import.

Comment: You said that you're loading data into DB2 database. Why did you also tag MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: Thanx @MarkBarinstein . I have tried your mentioned article earlier but it didn't worked. and I am also using the load instead of import. Is there any other way using ignore or some other way?

Comment: What's the error with the `WARNINGCOUNT 2` load modifier?

Comment: Or what's the problem with pipe use? The reason I ask is, that there is still no any other way to make load skip the 1-st line of a file without the ways specified at the link.